# winforms find nearest coordinates between two ellipses

Tags: winforms, coordinates, ellipse

I'm looking for an example that shows me how to find the nearest two points of each ellipse?

The two ellipses will not intersect each other.

How do you approach this?

Comment: Why is this winforms related? Have you tried your favorite searchengine? There is plenty of material out there for this problem. e.g. [Distance of closest approach of ellipses and ellipsoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_of_closest_approach_of_ellipses_and_ellipsoids) which is the first thing I find when I enter "closest point between two ellipses" in google

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by Mene is apparently referring to tangent ellipses what perhaps is not the case here. If your question referred to two ellipses located in random positions, perhaps you should try an iterative algorithm going through both contours; it is not "too clean" but I think that it is the best option for this problem. After implementing a first brute-force version going through the whole two contours, I would work on improving its efficiency by adding a quick pre-analysis determining the closest portions; for example: something on the lines of comparing the max./min. X/Y values of both ellipses to determine the two closest sub-sections (e.g., right1/up1 & left2/down2).